# Disowned "Stopped" job process still appears in process table

Tags: process, ps, background-process, jobs

I want to know why after disowning the stopped process, it is still appearing the process table

```
PING www.google.com (74.125.130.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.130.106: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=182 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.106: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=209 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.106: icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=213 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.106: icmp_seq=4 ttl=44 time=122 ms
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping www.google.com
anshul@anshul-Inspiron-N5010:~/Documents/workspace/shell$ jobs -l
[1]+ 10319 Stopped                 ping www.google.com
anshul@anshul-Inspiron-N5010:~/Documents/workspace/shell$ disown
bash: warning: deleting stopped job 1 with process group 10319
anshul@anshul-Inspiron-N5010:~/Documents/workspace/shell$ ps -ef | grep 10319
anshul   10319  9717  0 23:35 pts/25   00:00:00 ping www.google.com
```

Why still the process 10319 is showing, it should be deleted, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the process is **stopped**, not killed. So `ps` will still show it.

If you run `ps ax`, you will see its status is `T`. In this state, the process will do nothing until it receives a SIGCONT, then it will continue to run (if you type `fg` in your terminal, you'll see the process starting again from the point it stopped, so in your case the next `icmp_seq` will be 5).

**EDIT:** I forgot the `disown` part. Since you disowned the process, it doesn't appear anymore in `jobs`. For this reason, you can't `fg` it. However it is still present in the `ps` output with the `T` status. So as you said, you are still able to CONTINUE it with a `kill -sigcont <PID>`. Nevertheless, even you sent a SIGCONT, you can't *un-disown* it, that means you won't be able to make it run back in foreground of your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was unable to resume with fg, but was able to resume with kill -CONT <pid>

Comment: @Anveshak Yes, my bad. I totally forgot the `disown` part... In this case, you are right, running `fg` won't work, nevertheless the process still appear in `ps`. Anyway, you found the `kill -CONT` :) My apologies...